# How to setData in Singleton Arraylist from an Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, singleton

First : I'm on Android Studio(Java) and I try to setData from an Activity, in my Singleton (Arraylist) after a OnClick.

The data I would like to Update in my Singleton : Name, Street.

Second : Because it's an ArrayList do I need to use get(position) ? How can I specify that I want this
field of the list and not this one ( Exemple Street2 and not street1 ... )

Singleton :

```
public class PanelDataSource {
private static PanelDataSource mInstance;
private ArrayList<Panel> listPanel;

public static PanelDataSource getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null)
        mInstance = new PanelDataSource();

    return mInstance;
}

private PanelDataSource() {
    ArrayList<Block> listBlock = BlockDataSource.getInstance().getListBlock();
    ArrayList<Block> listBlockSPB = BlockDataSource.getInstance().getListBlockSPB();
    listPanel = new ArrayList<Panel>();
    listPanel.add(new Panel("Name", "Street", "ID 123456789", listBlock,listBlockSPB));
    listPanel.add(new Panel("Name2", "Steert2", "ID 234567890", listBlock,listBlockSPB));
}

// retrieve array from anywhere
public ArrayList<Panel> getListPanel() {
    return this.listPanel;
}}
```

The activity were I update my data ( I would like to use the OnClick for setData/Update in the Singleton ..

```
public class Activity_PanelSettingsEdit extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView panelSettingsEditId;
private EditText panelSettingsEditName, panelSettingsEditStreet;
private String name, street, id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_panelsettingsedit);


    panelSettingsEditId = findViewById(R.id.panelSettingsEditId);
    panelSettingsEditName = findViewById(R.id.PanelSettingsEditName);
    panelSettingsEditStreet = findViewById(R.id.panelSettingsEditStreet);

    Button buttonValidateSettingsEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonValidateSettingsEdit);
    buttonValidateSettingsEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent panelSettingsEditValidateIntent = new Intent(Activity_PanelSettingsEdit.this, Activity_PanelSettings.class);
            panelSettingsEditValidateIntent.putExtra("name",name);
            panelSettingsEditValidateIntent.putExtra("street",street);
            panelSettingsEditValidateIntent.putExtra("id",id);
            v.getContext().startActivity(panelSettingsEditValidateIntent);
        }

    });
    getData();
    setData();
}

private void getData() {
    name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    street = getIntent().getStringExtra("street");
    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

}

private void setData() {
    panelSettingsEditId.setText(id);
    panelSettingsEditName.setText(name);
    panelSettingsEditStreet.setText(street);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Part:

You can access your PanelDataSource singleton instance in onClick() and then can do something like below.

```
PanelDataSource.getInstance().getListPanel().add(new Panel(name, street, id, BlockDataSource.getInstance().getListBlock(),BlockDataSource.getInstance().getListBlockSPB()));
```

name: Name of Panel

street: Street name of Panel

id: Identification of Panel

and two `List<Block>`

Second Part:

If you need to access your panel with the name it would be good to save your data in {key, value} pair by using something like `HashMap`.
That way you can access your panel with StreetName if Streetname been used as a key to saving Panel data. But do make sure Streetname to be unique and no two Panel should share the same StreetName else it will be overridden with latest Panel.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Last question, how can I check if my data has been updated ( without using a view) (My view which should normally retrieve the new data does not update ... ?).  :)

Comment: Which data? The data in PanelDataSource?